# What's the probability that the earth's population decreases compared to the minute prior?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

First, disclaimer: that is a question I thought about and not something I found in a book so it might be flawed but I don't think so (someone correct me if I am wrong)

> According to the UN, $267$ babies are born each minute while according
> to another source $120$ people die each minute, since less amount of
> people are born compared to the amount of people who die, what's the
> probability that the population decreases after a minute?

What I thought about:

I thought about tackling the problem by representing the birth and death rate by $2$ independent random variable $X,Y$ respectively and finding $P(X-Y<0)$  by I have no experience when it comes to convolution of random variables and I don't know if my idea is reasonable/feasible, any help would be appreciated?

Comment: One problem is that you do not know the distributions of deaths: the possibility of large numbers of simultaneous deaths in natural or man-made disasters will affect the probability (ignoring this will lead to a very small number)

Comment: As observed, the answer depends on the underlying distributions for births and deaths during a one minute period.  If we assume both are independent and both follow Poisson distributions with means 267 (for births) and 120 (for deaths), then the distribution of the difference is a Skellam distribution - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061440/sum-and-difference-between-two-independent-poisson-random-variables)

Comment: and is there any way to find that or will it just be based on assumptions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe the population is actually _decreasing_ now.